# Turning a Pandas DataFrame into a SciPy Sparse CSC_Array

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a `pandas` dataframe that I'd like to turn into a sparse CSC_Array. My real dataframe is 200+ columns, but for this example I'm going to be working with just 4:

```
col1 = [1, 5, 6, 3, 3, 8, 6, 7, 4, 2]
col2 = [10, 40, 45, 28, 34, 85, 58, 65, 34, 18]
col3 = [4, 19, 25, 14, 11, 32, 28, 30, 11, 8]
col4 = [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'Cost': col1,
                          'Weight': col2,
                          'Value': col3,
                          'Type': col4})
```

For this example, I know that I could just manually write out a SciPy csc_array as such and it will work with the rest of my script:

```
cscArray = scipy.sparse.csc_array(
    scipy.sparse.vstack((
        scipy.sparse.csr_array(dataFrame.iloc[:0]),
        scipy.sparse.csr_array(dataFrame.iloc[:1]),
        scipy.sparse.csr_array(dataFrame.iloc[:2]),
        scipy.sparse.csr_array(dataFrame.iloc[:3]),
    ), format='csc')
)
```

But I need to find a way to generalize it since I can't do this for 200+ columns.

I've read similar SO posts, and I've tried single-line conversions like `cscArray = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(dataFrame.values)`, but nothing seems to work with my larger process like the manual example I've shown. Is there an easy way to generalize turning a large pandas dataframe into a SciPy vstack/csc_array like the example I've shown above? I feel like even looping over `len(dataFrame.columns)` in someway would work? But speed is of major importance and I fear that might be too slow? Thank you.

Comment: note `dataFrame.iloc[:n]` will slice on rows but not columns. Are you sure with the given description?

Comment: That `cscArray` is weird, made up of 0,1,2,3 rows of the dataframe.  There's nothing 'sparse' about it.  What is wrong with using `values`.  Give us a clearer idea of what the desired sparse array is supposed to be like.

Comment: When given a numpy array (or dataframe values), `sparse...._array`, uses `np.nonzero` to find the nonzero values, and makes a `coo` matrix to store those along with their coordinates.  It can make a further conversion to `csc` (and from `matrix` to `array`).  In any case, the basic input is in the `coo` style, with `data`, `row`, and `col` arrays.  If you aim to do much work with `sparse`, familiarize yourself with that storage and input method.  In terms of memory use you should have 60-+% zeros, and computation sake I suggest 5% nonzeros.  Otherwise sparse has little value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DataFrame.to_numpy()` method to pass the dense array to `csc_array`.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csc_array
import pandas as pd

# making sparse data
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
N = 100
M = 100
fill_percent = 0.05
nonzero_indices = rng.choice(N*M, int(N*M*fill_percent), False)
data = np.zeros((N,M))
data[np.unravel_index(nonzero_indices, (N,M))] = rng.random(int(N*M*fill_percent))

# creating sparse array from pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
sparse_array = csc_array(df.to_numpy())

assert np.all(data == sparse_array.todense())
```

Note: I created some sparse data because it only makes sense to use a sparse array if you have sparse data. I'm not sure why the example in the question is not sparse.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! It's become clear to me that I need to do a better job understanding my own task at hand, and to formulate a better example-question before I continue.

Comment: @CoolGuyHasChillDay Meaning?